# Setting up the CarND environment, error: AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

Tags: gpu, conda, miniconda

I am following [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/launch-a-gpu-backed-google-compute-engine-instance-and-setup-tensorflow-keras-and-jupyter-902369ed5272) to set up GPU enabled GCP VM machine with Tensorflow, Keras, Jupyter. I am stuck in the middle of the instruction: Setting up the CarND environment (about midway in the instructions)

This is my machine config: ubuntu 16.04 running conda 4.5.11 with python 3.7.0

1. Using this version: https://github.com/udacity/CarND-Term1-Starter-Kit/blob/master/environment-gpu.yml
2. After broken environment, I tried `conda env remove -n carnd-term1` and then again `conda env create -f environment-gpu.yml`.

Even after this, I am still getting the same error message:
This is the error message I am getting, and I cannot seemt to figure out what seems to be the problem.

````
```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER_NAME/miniconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2869, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "/home/USER_NAME/miniconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2663, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```
````

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it after 4 days, and it works fine now. No problem is detected anymore.